# PHP - Using special characters in XML tag

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, addchild

Hi I'm using PHP and I wrote an application that creates and fills a SimpleXMLObject with the results of a database query. The results are saved as tags. I accomplish this with

```html
if (!isset($set->$parttemp)) {
$parttemp = "$parttemp &#40 $groupname &#41";
$set = $set->addChild($parttemp);
}
```

My problem is, I want to use special characters in the XML tags. With a bit of research I found out that you need to use the code of that character for example for "(" you need to write `&#40;`

But if you want to use those codes within a tag you also need to replace the tags with that code. For example for <permission(s)/> I need to write `&lt; permission &#40; s &#41; / &gt;`

That would not be a big deal but the tags are set from the addChild operation so i can't manipulate them. Is there another solution?

Comment: I don't think you can use parentheses in an XML element name. Take a look [here](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html).

Comment: hmmm.. from what i understand you have to create the tags also with the corresponding code like recommended under w3

Comment: Part of your confusion seems to be over what a child element is. `&lt; permission &#40; s &#41; / &gt;`, is not an element, it's just some text, like `foo`, or `M. Anderson`. `<foo>hello</foo>` is an element called `foo`, with text content `hello`. A child element is a structural part of the result document, and its name has to follow certain rules, regardless of how you try to escape things.

Comment: oh, I see. So what I tried earlier just created plain text and not an actual child element. Thank you for clearing me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punctuation characters like "(" aren't valid in XML element or attribute names. Trying to escape them (for example as a decimal character reference `&#40;`) is no use - character references aren't recognized within the name.

You'll have to find some application-level way of encoding the string as a valid name. For example, I've seen people use `<permission_x28_s_x29_>`.

Usually, though, I would tend to prefer `<element name="permissions(s)">`.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. Manipulation of the name attribute seems like a good solution, I will try it out and write here as soon as I have the result.